# Time for yogurt to heat and cool when yogurt maker is on and off

Tags: thermodynamics

I have the yogurt maker Moulinex DJC141. I put the yogurt in the glass containers with no lid and covered with a kitchen towel. It reaches 54 ºC when it should stay between 43 and 46 ºC. I want to know how long would it take for the yogurt to go from 43 to 46 ºC and cool from 46 to 43 ºC so I can get a programmable plug to switch the yogurt maker on and off to stay between those temperatures. Assume a kitchen temperature of 20 ºC.

Comment: How much yogurt is there?  Don’t you think that’s pretty important?7

Comment: It has 7 glasses with a capacity for 140 ml each.

Comment: You can build a simple model based on Newton's Law of Cooling but it would be easier (and prob. more accurate) to simply accurately **measure** the heating/cooling cycles a few times.

Comment: How do you know the temperature of the yogurt? Do you measure it with a thermometer or use a built-in function on the yogurt maker?

Comment: With a digital food thermometer. The yogurt maker doesn't have a way of knowing the yogurt temperature.